# Item-Level Permissions (Edit only their own but, read everyones)

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have a list which I've set item-level permissions on. I set it to allow users to read all items and only edit their own items...

The issue is that if I do this then I can still edit all items...

If I change it so that I can only read my own and only edit my own then it works as expected...

Anyone have any thoughts on why this would be occurring and a solution...

I've set the list up to only allow one user account with contribute rights for testing purposes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you change permission in a list Advance Settings, it still let contributors to go to EditForm but once contributors try to save item, that doesn't belong to them, it show error message that you don't have permissions.

give it a try, create an item by some user let say User1, then try to modify that item using User2 credentials (User must have only Contributor right on the site/list), it will let you go to EditForm but wont let you save item.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a list manager (e.g., a site owner)?  List managers have extra permission.

Comment: i'm loging in with a user that has bare bones permissions

Comment: I'm stumped unless there is a weird situation where the account you are using is also a application pool owner or something.  I realize this contradicts your comment, but that wouldn't show up in the site permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This only works if your user does not have permissions to edit all items on the list by based on the site permissions. E.g. if your users has contribute permissions to the site, that will override the individual item permissions.